# Why html-element text doesn't replace?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use javascript (jQuery) to toggle text of html-element (span):

```
function TextToogle(element, text) {
   if (element.html() == '-' + text) {
       element.html(text.replace(element.html(), '+' + text));
   }
   else {
       element.html(text.replace(element.html(), '-' + text));
   }
}
```

I give two arguments for my function:
1) element  - html Object
2) text - default text of span

My goal is toggle the span text from "+text" to "-text" and vice versa.

But script doesn't work correctly. When function toggle text to "+text", as result I see "text". The toggle to "-text" works correctly.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle: jsfiddle.net?

Comment: you have made a simple problem very complicated

Comment: Dealing with text.. very unreliable approach.

Comment: Rahul Desai, Yes, I can. I will attach link after 5 minutes.

Comment: dfsq, What is better approach to solve my task?

Comment: @PellePenna I made no comment on his/her capabilities. Read the comment again. I commented on the approach.

Comment: Wrong of me, though she/he don't need that, she/he need help with an issue

Comment: @Feel I would suggest to toggle CSS class with `:before` pseudo element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on you is comparison (`element.html() == '-' + text`) your function can be simpler. You don't need `text.replace(element.html(), '+' + text)` part:

```
function TextToogle(element, text) {
   if (element.text() == '-' + text) {
       element.text('+' + text);
   }
   else {
       element.text('-' + text);
   }
}
```

However relying on text comparison is not ideal. I would use CSS which is not text dependent:

```
$('.text-toggle').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

CSS

```
.text-toggle:before {
    content: '+';
}
.text-toggle.active:before {
    content: '-';
}
```

There is obvious advantage here is that you can style your +/- easily, you can set a background image, chage font-size, etc. While you would'n be able this with your original approach.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/mvj5c/

Comment: And you are first. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I would just replace inside a callback, seems so much simpler

```
element.text(function(_, txt) {
    return txt.replace(/[+-]/g, function(x) {
        return x == '+' ? '-' : '+';
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pSDXf/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function toggleText(text) {
    return {'-':'+', '+':'-'}[text[0]]+text.slice(1);
}

element.html(toggleText(element.html()));
```

Answer (score 0):

See simple example.

You've text `-abc`. Now it's fail on both of the checks.

Why not do this

```
function TextToogle(element, text) {
   var check = text.splice(0, 1);
   if (check === "-") {
       element.html("+" + text.substring(1, text.length));
   }
   else {
       element.html("-" + text.substring(1, text.length));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$('span').click(function(){
  var 
     $this = $(this),
     thisText = $this.text();
  $this.text($this.text() === "-" + thisText ? ("+" + thisText) : ("-" + thisText));

});
```